# Why is this ul exceeding the size of it's div?

Tags: html, css, menu, width, html-lists

Although `li.textmenu` has width: 140px, padding: 5px, and div.textmenu has width: 150px, the one list item i've made so far has a big left margin, and extends beyond the right edge of the div by at least 30px. What could be causing this and how can I restrict it's width?

http://www.briligg.com/frailty.html

**CSS**

```
div.textmenu {
  background-color: #3b3b3b;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 30px 10px 0 30px;
}

li.textmenu {
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  width: 140px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="textmenu"> 
  <ul> 
    <li class="textmenu">
      <a class="pink" href="http://www.briligg.com/frailty.html#culture">Stress Causes Addiction</a>
    </li> 
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Try inspecting the page with a tool like firebug, which can show you the size and margins of each box. Maybe some box is bigger than you thought, or text spilled out of a box (check CSS `overflow`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add a zip/uni reset to the top of your css file?

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

( Put that exactly as is at the very top of CSS to override browser default margins/padding ).

Most likely the `ul` is being given default padding/margin, so this is to counter-act it.

Comment: yep. That worked... Now i'll have to edit the margins and padding of some other stuff that the browser was handling, but i guess that's better coding anyhow...
thanks!

Comment: Yes, it makes it much more consistent. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `ul` does not have padding and margin of its own, by resetting it with `padding:0;margin:0;`

Comment: Doing it this way would have saved me the need to set margins and padding for everything, but i've gone with the general reset, of putting * {padding: 0; margin: 0;} at the beginning of the css.

Comment: @briligg, see http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ for a general good reset (*not just margin/padding..*)

Answer (score 2):

The ul has a margin and padding set it on by the browser. You'll want to remove this:

`div.textmenu ul {margin:0;padding:0;}`

Only the padding affects the width, but you'll probably want to take off the margin too.

Answer (score 2):

Its like smeridan said. There are for *all* html elements preset styling properties.

I recommend you to use the reset css by Eric Meyer: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

You can include it at the top of your document. After that you have more control about your desired styling.

Comment: That version gets into a lot of stuff i don't think i'll need for a site of this complexity... but it's an interesting resource. I'm going to lookup more 'css reset' stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've calculated the exact width and height of the Li you want to fix inside the Div by making sure the DIV has enough space within it.

```
div.textmenu {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 30px 10px 0 30px;
    }
    li.textmenu {
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    width: 140px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    }
```

Since you made the padding: 5px, calculated by the 2xwidth + height of the Li, the Li should exceed 150px width of the Div box. you can fix by reducing your padding pixel of the LI.